# Apply separate CSS to one of the multiple instances of same React custom component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have two custom components called Grid and FieldValue and I use the FieldValue component multiple times on a particular page. I am using a class name called `.black` for all the FieldValue components. Now, I want to use a different class name called `.blue-pointer` where the data in FieldValue says view2. please help me understand how to do it.

Components on the page look like below

```
<Grid>
    <FieldValue data={'view1'}/>
    <FieldValue data={'view2'}/>
    <FieldValue data={'view3'}/>
</Grid>
```

And the FieldValue is defined as below,

```
class FieldValue extends React.Component<>{
    render(){
         <div className="black">
          {'testView'}
         </div>
    }
}
```

And the CSS is defined as below

```
.black{
    color:#4d546d;
}
.blue-pointer {
    color: #0070d2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `props` from your component :

```
class FieldValue extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.data === 'view2' ? 'blue-pointer' : 'black'}>
        {'testView'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw., what does this `<>` in `extends React.Component<>{` mean?

Comment: It is a react type definition. You can read more here I guess https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/.

Comment: I think you can remove `<>` since you're not using it here.

Comment: Thanks @Striped 
I am passing some props there in <>

Comment: @Konekoya Done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `className` as a `prop`, and give it a default value of `'black'`.

```
class FieldValue extends React.Component<> {
  static defaultProps = {
    className: 'black'
  }

  render() {
    const { className } = this.props

    <div className={className}>
      {'testView'}
    </div>}
}
```

For the default case, you don't need to change anything:

```
<FieldValue data={'view1'} /> // Still uses the `black` style.
```

When you want to change the class name, use:

```
<FieldValue data={'view2'} className='blue-pointer' />
```